# Managing time zone data in jpg files for use in Google Photos

Tags: metadata, google-photos

I wish to create a Google Photos album which displays my images in the order that I dictate. My problem would not exist if Google Photos would offer the option of sorting images in an album by filename, but instead it only offers sorting by newest, oldest or manually (the latter I do not wish to do). I have created an album of about 300 images, but they come from three different devices each of which has recorded time differently, meaning that my images are all out of order when uploaded to a Google Photos album. It seems Google has a mind of its own and sorts my images according to some field not known or visible to me, meaning that no matter what attempt I make of manipulation of time fields, I cannot achieve the desired result. Although by no means certain, I have come to the conclusion that I need to make the UTC field of my images all the same. When that step is accomplished I believe that I can apply the techniques that I do know to alter the time taken data and force the images to stay in order once uploaded to Google Photos. Question is: can anyone show me how to make the UTC field the same across a folder of image files. I know to how to advance or retard UTC of files, but not how to apply a technique across a number of files to put that field to a single value.

Comment: Do you want to change the UTC field of the images on your PC (and then upload them), or to change them directly in Google Photos?

Comment: Thanks Winston. Yes, that is what I want to do. However, after a few long hours trying to work through this issue, I have found a solution. I am a bit of a beginner with this sort of file manipulation, but some experimentation with program exiftool yielded the desired outcome. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Sorry Winston, I wasn't clear. I answered your "either-or" question with "yes". The correct answer is that I wish to change the UTC at the PC, then upload. In any event, as I said above, I have found the solution.

Comment: CB24 please consider creating an answer for the solution you found, so that others can benefit in the future. Glad you figured it out!